# Remove loop.last in jinja 2.7.1

Tags: pyramid, jinja2

According the [release notes](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/changelog/) of Jinja2, the special variable of for-loop named **loop.last** has been removed.

> Accessing last on the loop context no longer causes the iterator to be consumed into a list

So, is there a replacement?

Answer (score 2):

That's not what the release notes are saying, it's merely a change in the implementation to avoid some memory usage.

You can find the details about this issue on [github](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/pull/92).